# MongoDB - Search by keyword 'such' not working

Tags: mongodb, text-search

**Scenario**

Searching for word `such` not working in MongoDB.

**Steps to reproduce**

In mongo shell:

```
use test
db.createCollection("data")
db.data.insert({"value": "word1 such word3 word4"})
db.data.createIndex({value: "text"})
db.data.find({$text: {$search: "word3"}}) -> returns the inserted document
db.data.find({$text: {$search: "such"}}) -> returns nothing
```

**Desired behaviour**

When searching for word `such` the inserted document should be returned.

Comment: "such" is a default stopword and not included in the full text index. Why was this closed, the question is perfectly clear?

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, I found the list of [stop-words](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/fts/stop_words_english.txt) for english.